# Get Female Friends facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get female friends facebook

```
$fql = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/fql?q=SELECT sex, uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND sex = 'female' LIMIT 10&access_token=$access_token";
$fqlresult = file_get_contents($fql); 
$f = json_decode($fqlresult, true);
$friends1 = $f['data']['1']['uid'];
```

I tried this but not returning anything.

Comment: If you are using API v2.0 you will only get friends that have granted user_friends to your app

Comment: no its old app works with fql.

Comment: Fql works in api v2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can try using graph api to get friends gender and filter using php code to get female friends:

```
$query =  "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me?fields=friends{gender,name}&acess_token=$your_access_token";
$results = file_get_contents($query);
$freinds = json_decode($results , true);
foreach($freinds as $friend)
{
      if($friend['gender']=='female')
      {
          echo $friend['name'].'<br>';
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The FQL query `SELECT sex, uid FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND sex = 'female' LIMIT 10`

is correct and works (I tried it), your overall API query needs to be something like

`https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=`

not

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/fql?q=`

remove `me`